# Value is printing twice rather than once

Tags: python, printing, python-requests

I have this code. The count of values from the first url always displays twice. But the sum is right.

So I get

```
4
4
2
6
```

Instead of

```
4
2
6
```

```
def count_blocklist_entries():
    urls = ['https://rad.net/Easylist.txt', 'https://rad.net/Admiral.txt']
    entry_dict = {}
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        lengthers = len(response.text.splitlines())
        entry_dict.update({url: lengthers})
        print(lengthers)
        print(sum(entry_dict.values()))

count_blocklist_entries()
```

Expecting to not get the first integer twice.

Comment: Well, the first 4 is the lengthers for the 1st url, the 2nd the sum of the only entry :) ; so move the print(sum... out of the for loop!

Comment: Duh... I need a break. Thanks. Make this the solution and I'll select it when the time limit is up.

Comment: Don't worry about it: the simplest mistakes are often the hardest to spot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the sum printing to the actual end of the code, after the "for" loop:

```
def count_blocklist_entries():
    urls = ['https://rad.net/Easylist.txt', 'https://rad.net/Admiral.txt']
    entry_dict = {}
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        lengthers = len(response.text.splitlines())
        entry_dict.update({url: lengthers})
        print(lengthers)
    print(sum(entry_dict.values()))

count_blocklist_entries()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is occurring within the entry_dict variable:

```
Iteration 1: {'https://rad.net/Easylist.txt': 4}
Sum of values in dictionary = 4
Iteration2: {'https://rad.net/Easylist.txt': 4, 'https://rad.net/Admiral.txt': 2}
Sum of values in dictionary = 6
```

If you wanted to only print out the `sum(entry_dict.values())` after adding all the urls to the entry_dict dictionary, that line should be added outside the for loop.